Received two emails with different customer numbers from the USPTO
I have submitted the forms for the customer number and electronic verification system.
I got two emails, each with different customer numbers.
I called customer service. They said that I can use either one when submitting a patent application.
I don't see any of those number on my uspto.gov account.
Where can I find these numbers on my uspto.gov account to confirm?

You can call the EBC help desk but I think your online account and customer number are not tied to each other. When you file an application online you tell it your customer number.
